# How would i reconnect Entity Frameworks connection to the DB when the connection is lost

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, mvvm

I am working on a `MVVM` project using Entity Framework `5.0`.

I connect to a hosted DB and sometimes Entity Framework looses connection to the DB.

What would be the best way to reconnect the connection to the DB when the connection was lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connection is broken during saving your changes you simply get exception. Whole saving is done in transaction which is not committed due to the exception and EF doesn't mark its current changes set as completed. You can simply try to save changes again when that specific exception happens - EF will try to open a new connection and execute the same transaction

---

for ex.:
well, maybe something like this:

```
public virtual void SubmitChanges()
{
    if (DataContext != null)
    {               
        try
        {
             DataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception whenILostMyConnection)
        {
             SubmitChanges(); //recall the sumbitChanges
        }
    }             
}
```

Comment: Okay sounds good, but what do i do when i am in a ViewModel and it tries to do a LINQ query and fails because the connection is closed or broken? I have already registered an event that fires when the connection state changes and it seems to not fire when i loose connection to the DB. So how do i handle this issue?

Comment: I'm not very competent in giving "good" design pattern solutions, but i think the proper outcome for this will be if you centralize your db manipulation methods, so that you could easily manage your transactions against database, for, ex create some Data Manipulator class, which manages simple operations like SaveChanges, Commit and so on.

Comment: Won't this be a infinite loop if the connection keeps failing?

Comment: It's a basic Idea, you must handle specific exceptions in order to decide weather to continue or not

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave it here in case someone, like me, is looking for an answer to this question.

Add `options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()` to the `OnConfiguring` configuration:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFMiscellanous.ConnectionResiliency;Trusted_Connection=True",
            options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
}
```

Read more [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency).

Answer (score 0):

You can see answer in Windows Azure source code. It's common for Azure CRUD operations to put them into loops which retries to do the same operation for several times cause for some specific exceptions. But you must be very carefully with exceptions you what handle for retries cause in most cases it can make you app slower.